# Existe pacote que faça stepwise e análise a multicolinearidade simultaneamente?

Tags: r

Estou desenvolvendo um modelo e gostaria de saber se alguém conhece algum pacote que faça o stepwise e já vá medindo a correlação entre as variáveis dependentes, buscando o melhor modelo sem colinearidade alta.

Estou usando o pacote `caret` com as funções `findCorrelation` e desenvolvendo o modelo com `train(..., method = "glmStepAIC")`.

Porém queria uma função que já medisse tudo de uma vez e encontrasse o melhor modelo pensando primeiramente nas variáveis que melhor descriminam ao invés de primeiramente tirar a multicolinearidade. Pensei em uma estratégia pra fazer isso rodando o `glmStepAIC` e depois testar a colinearidade, e eu mesmo ir removendo as variáveis correlacionadas priorizando as mais significantes, rodar novamente o `glmStepAIC` sem as variáveis que removi, verificar novamente a correlação, remover mais uma vez as altamente correlacionadas priorizando o poder de descriminação e assim sucessivamente, porém esse processo é muito longo/lento/repetitivo. Alguém conhece um outro meio ou uma função/pacote que faça isso automático?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difícil ter uma função que faça exatamente o que você quer (desconheço). Quando você faz um stepwise AIC, ele primeiro vai selecionar o modelo com o menor AIC (ele não olha para a multicolineariedade, mas é evidente que as estimativas dos betas e de variância de alguma forma são afetadas or isso), e após isso, você faz a análise de multicolinearidade via `car::vif`, por exemplo.

Mas ao invés disso, você poderia ajustar uma regressão com penalização. Ela por si só já consegue acomodar os problemas de multicolinearidade e p > n. As mais comuns são:

- Regressão com penalização `Lasso` (Seleciona variáveis, fixando alguns parâmetro iguais a 0);
- Regressão com penalização `Ridge` (Todos as variáveis iniciais, permanecem no modelo, no entanto, algumas com os parâmetros próximos de 0);
- Regressão com penalização `Elastic Net` (fica no 'meio' termo das 2 de cima);

Elas estão implementadas no pacote `glmnet`, cuja documentação pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html)

Comment: Além disso, o `caret` consegue ajustar modelos que utilizam o pacote `glmnet`, como podemos ver [neste link](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html).